# Тренировка ajax запросов

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

Делаю учебное приложение на react, которое впоследствии будет выложено на хостинг. Предполагается, что оно будет обращаться к json файлам через ajax. Подскажите пожалуйста, куда можно выложить эти json файлы, чтобы потренироваться работе с удаленным сервером?

Answer (score 1):

Для тестовых заданий и тому подобное - часто используют http://randomuser.ru/ например. Там описано как пользоваться.
 для  своих апишек  можно использовать https://www.postman.com/
- но там нужно научится разбираться. хотя штука полезная.

Comment: Не подойдет, мне нужно поработать именно со своими json файлами.

Comment: тогда  только свой сервер.  локальный или поднять   где-то. есть куча  примеров локальных серверов на ноде. быстро и просто. можно попробовать

Comment: @EgorG, забыл про postman.  если разберешься - вообще супер. очень часто на проектах используют